# Preserving the state of the current stylesheet

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to preserver the state of the stylesheet after it is being changed.I am doing that by storing a value in a cookie.This is my code:

```
var content = $("#content");
var state = $.cookie("layoutState");

if (state === "grid") {
    content.removeClass("content-list").addClass("content-grid");
    console.log($.cookie("layoutState"));
}

if (state === "list") {
    content.removeClass("content-grid").addClass("content-list");
    console.log($.cookie("layoutState"));
}

$("#list").on("click", function (e) {
    $.cookie("layoutState", "list");
    content.removeClass("content-grid").addClass("content-list");
    e.preventDefault();
})

$("#grid").on("click", function (e) {
    $.cookie("layoutState", "grid");
    content.removeClass("content-list").addClass("content-grid");
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

The click events work perfectly.The problem I think lies in the two if conditions I have.
For some reason the cookie value changes sometimes after page change.I would like the state of the cookie to change only on click event.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are not editing the cookie value somewhere else in the code?

Comment: no this is the only piece of javascript I have written